# Devise with OmniAuth for facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am new to rails and I would like to allow user login/registration to my site with Devise and Omniauth.

So I followed OmniAuth: Overview (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview). But I can't get it working, it is showing this error shown below when I try test it on heroku production.

```
NoMethodError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook

undefined method `find_for_facebook_oauth' for #<Class:0x007f9bc0a3aa30>
```

& below are my codes which should be the same as OmniAuth: Overview, any help will be much appreciated.

```
user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:recoverable
  :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :address, :mobile, :provider, :uid
   # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :pins, :dependent => :destroy
end

def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user
    user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                         provider:auth.provider,
                         uid:auth.uid,
                         email:auth.info.email,
                         password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                         )
  end
  user
end


Devise.rb

  # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
  # config.omniauth_path_prefix = "/my_engine/users/auth"
config.secret_key = '75f6735f226e8ea0484f2abd55f78efee516306e8a0e69ac2cd68f50ce0f44078af9b3497bf49db3874a523c573b2e22eec01d508f703e32887de8c8f44740cb'

require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, "3223424", "52341341341134", :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
{:scope => 'email, offline_access', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}} 


My Gemfiles 

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'oauth2'


Routes.rb

Dine::Application.routes.draw do


  get "home/index"

  resources :pins
  resources :pin 

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user

  root :to => 'pins#index'
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'
  get 'weekly' => 'pages#weekly'
  get 'shop' => 'pages#shop'
  get 'service' => 'pages#service'
    get 'privacy' => 'pages#privacy'
  get 'test' => 'pages#test'
  get 'recipies' => 'pages#recipies'  
  get 'know' => 'pages#know'
  get 'give' => 'pages#give' 
  get 'how' => 'pages#how' 


  match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact', :via => :get
  match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post

  match 'inform' => 'inform#new', :as => 'inform', :via => :get
  match 'inform' => 'inform#create', :as => 'inform', :via => :post

  as :user do
  match '/user/confirmation' => 'confirmations#update', :via => :put, :as => :update_user_confirmation
  end
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :confirmations => "confirmations" }

end


users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1):

the find_for_facebook_oauth should be in the User class. like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :registerable, 
         :rememberable, 
         :trackable, 
         :validatable, 
         :omniauthable, 
         :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :address, :mobile, :provider, :uid

  has_many :pins, :dependent => :destroy

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                           provider:auth.provider,
                           uid:auth.uid,
                           email:auth.info.email,
                           password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
    end
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi William, thanks for the help. But I think you only added an extra end at the very bottom of User, is that correct? I did add that and now the site on heroku is broken. I also copied and pasted your complete code, and that also broke the site.

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: Hi William, I just get: something wrong with your app, check your logs if you are the owner of the app etc... So I have added the heroku logs below my codes in the top.

Comment: Sorry, not sure why it's not showing up, here it is the error on heroku logs.  2013-10-08T09:10:40.902142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=labdisrupt.herokuapp.com fwd="1.162.75.191" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-08T09:10:45.205190+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=labdisrupt.herokuapp.com fwd="1.162.75.191" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: And running it on your machine?

Comment: Hi William, I ran it on Heroku. From the tutorial, it mentioned that the codes are different for development on rails server and production on Heroku, so I went straight for the Heroku setup. The error message when I ran it on rails server is the following   {
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: \u61c9\u7528\u7a0b\u5f0f\u8a2d\u7f6e\u7121\u6cd5\u63a5\u53d7\u7279\u5b9a\u7db2\u5740\u3002",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}